# Is it possible to execute binary files in java?

Tags: java, binaries

I have a list of binaries written in Java, Ada, C, and Python and I want to execute them.
How can I do that? 
Are there any JVM binding to those languages?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If all you want to do is execute existing applictions, you can use the `exec` methods from the [`java.io.runtime`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) namespace.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process ps = rt.exec("path to my executable.exe");
```

Comment: For later versions it has moved to java.lang.Runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here is a link to a good blog article on how to do it: [Running system commands in Java](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016).

The gist of it is that you need to do the following:

```
// run the Unix "ps -ef" command
// using the Runtime exec method:
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -ef");
```

You can pretty much put any command in there but the only gotcha that I have encountered in be aware of system environment variables like the PATH that you are running your JVM in.

Comment: Updated (2010) version of that article: http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to interact with the binary API's, use:

- [Java Native Access (JNA)](https://github.com/twall/jna/): for loading and calling DLLs.
- [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface): for wrapping a C library in Java.